# Object displacement - ocean of hexagon tiles

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I want to make an ocean of cubes / hexagon tiles with varying  z locations. There was this guy with extrusion images and I wonder how he made it.

Like this... [image]

however, in the process, mine looks more like this:
[image]

I used a cloud map and joined all hexagon cylinders into one object. Then i wanted to displace only each element from the object along the z axis.....

That was the plan at least. Could you point towards a solution? Maybe you got a better idea how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this static, or to be animated?

Comment: static as still landscape

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just scale all of the individual parts down to a size of 0 in the UVmap (using individual origins as scaling center). That way, each part will stay intact, but will be displaced as a whole according to the value of your noise where that UV island resides.

UV Map:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Edit: if you use a displacement modifier instead of shader displacement, it's easier to control the axis of displacement:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is such a smart solution. Thanks for sharing :).

Comment: Hey hey, thanks for the info! Cool idea! Though maybe i did smth. wrong in the creation? They still move as one or rather all in the at the same value and are fairly broken. Did you use an array to place the cylinders? Maybe it is because they are differently split? (i just created arrays of them and joined them afterwards together. Thanks a lot for the help ;D greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Avion32 - I also placed them via array modifiers that were applied afterwards. Then enter edit mode - UV project from top view, select all faces in the UV editor, scale them to 0 on individual origins and all is set

Comment: lol,dear @tobkum, your help is greatly appreciated. I come from 3dSMax and your way seems the closest i would also do it. Somehow i mess it up though. May i ask with this short vid how its done? Let me show you what i did and what i want to do ;)    https://youtu.be/PcBvyDy-BxI

Comment: added .blend example file to my answer :)

Comment: for what ever reason: just did it with fresh mind and cubes.. .. works flawless. I think the issue is that i selected the top faces instead of all faces.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that part in your video, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to use Instancing. Make a well-subdivided plane as parent, single hex object as child. Enable Instancing on the plane. Put a Wave or Displace modifier on the plane.